# Index JSON in SQLAlchemy on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using JSON in my SQLAlchemy DB model:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

class Customer(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  custcontext_json = db.Column(JSON, default=lambda: {})
```

Now I have this query that is getting too slow:

```
customers = Customer.query.filter(
  Customer.clientid == clientid,
  or_(
    func.lower(Customer.custcontext_json['cinfo', 'userName'].astext.cast(Unicode)).contains(searchterm.lower()),
    func.lower(Customer.custcontext_json['cinfo', 'home', 'sign'].astext.cast(Unicode)).contains(searchterm.lower())
  ),

  or_(
    Customer.custcontext_json['cinfo', 'home', 'status'].astext == 'pre',
    Customer.custcontext_json['cinfo', 'home', 'status'].astext == 'during',
    Customer.custcontext_json['cinfo', 'lastChange'].astext.cast(DateTime) > pendulum.now('UTC').subtract(days=14)
  )
  ).all()
```

Is it possible to index the table for this query. Or at least parts of it?

Comment: Can you please get sample query and its query plan. You can make use of JSONBform  and GIN indexes which can speed up things for you.

Comment: -- use jsonb form of the method instead of the json form as well.
-- if you have tags use this " ->" instead of "->>"  cos "->" will return the json object and "->>" will return the tag/ property as an integer or text.

Comment: were you able to get it working ?

Comment: While my background is in MySQL, I assume that even in Postgresql the use of a function on a column will prevent your database from using an index on that column. That is backed up by comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44023031/10682164) although it sounds like you can create indexes on function results too based on one of the answers. Ignoring that potential option for a second, indexing a text-based column will only be useful if you are searching from the start of the string. Perhaps you could extract these attributes into separate columns that you index.

Comment: Doing contains - even in normal SQL is a performance killer. If you did starts with you may yields slighly improved performance.

Comment: It may be worth looking at something like ElasticSearch instead for your problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [JSONB](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) as format with higher density. But that is not an answer.

Please look [here](https://medium.com/code-on-a-boat/searching-postgres-json-columns-using-sqlalchemy-aece6ae5b0e9). Operators for JSON type in PostgreSQL, you can get from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html). I would like to get your create table, to reproduce something at my side. Any way. I would start with something like this:

```
create table customer (clientid serial, custcontext_json jsonb);

create index on customer (
  (CAST((custcontext_json->'cinfo'->'userName') AS TEXT)),
  (CAST((custcontext_json->'cinfo'->'home'->'sign') AS TEXT)),
  (CAST((custcontext_json->'cinfo'->'home'->'status') AS TEXT)));
```